# React Admin - send custom query during edit/create record

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-admin, react-typescript

I have a simple form to edit camera

```
export const CameraEdit: FC<ResourceComponentProps> = (props: ResourceComponentProps) => (
  <Edit {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <TextInput source="name" />
      <TextInput source="connection" />
      <Button variant="contained" label="Preview"></Button>
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

When I click on `Preview` button I want to

1. fetch preview from backend (using GraphQL)
2. download the image
3. show it on the right side of form

I don't know how to:

1. issue additional async query (not related to editing data) as in normal react app I had container and component
2. download the image (result of query)
3. add additional div to `SimpleForm` - I've read it can handle only direct inputs

Comment: I guess the naive solution would be to use a `useLazyQuery` with Apollo inside of the component. In the end, the React Admin app is just a regular React app. Inside of the `SimpleForm`, you can render pretty much anything you want.

Comment: @Herku I used to have separated application layers: container to communicate with backend and component as presentation layer. I suites me and I'd like to copy it here

Comment: What I want to say is that it doesn't matter what kind of component you use for your edit. This can be one of the containers that you describe. You will just have to forward all the props that are meant for the `<Edit />` component.